# Difference between tomorrow never comes and tomorrow will never come

Tags: phrases, idioms, popular-refrains

What is the difference between `tomorrow never comes` and `tomorrow will never come`? A friend said that `Tomorrow never comes` is a saying. Then Why is the latter not a saying too? Are their meanings the same or not?

Comment: "Tomorrow never comes" is a general truth: no tomorrow ever comes, because when it does come it's today. "Tomorrow will never come" is said of a **particular** tomorrow, when you are eager for it to arrive and the wait seems to take forever.

Comment: @StoneyB Thank you. Now I could see it clearly. Thanks again.

Comment: I'd add to Stoney's answer that, though 'Tomorrow never comes' _is_ an idiom (a set saying, as your friend says) - and the three-word saying can be used as a complete sentence (but as part of a dialogue), 'Tomorrow will never come' would almost certainly be used as part of a contextualising sentence. "I can't wait for the wedding - it feels like tomorrow will never come."

Comment: Or, since both are necessarily true (in the same sense of _tomorrow_), each implies the other and _Tomorrow will never come_ may be used in the same admonitive sense as the idiom. It's only its frequency and relative fixedness of sense that makes _Tomorrow never comes_ an idiom; if the longer one was more common in that sense, it would be, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Tomorrow never comes" is used when you talk broadly about situations in general.
"Tomorrow will never come" is used specifically to a certain situation.